# Where to define XML Styles

Tags: android, material-design

I dived into app development with material design.

My min SDK version is 21.

Should I define my styles in

```
res/values
```

or

```
res/values-v21
```

?

If they are defined in values-21, will they be only available for SDK version 21 or for SDK version 23 too?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The values-vXX are for API level XX and up.

So if you place some values in values-v21, they will be available for both 21 and 23.

(SDK-version is the same as API level)